# Compaq Deskpro EN: 1 long beep, 2 short beeps, caps lock flashes

Tags: post

I have a Compaq Deskpro EN and I am getting one long beep and two short beeps on bootup, the caps lock light is flashing and no video. The case has a sticker which says this means "no video." But what video? There is no graphics card, at best there is a 2D accelerator integrated in the chipset somehow.

Any tips on how to go about fixing this would be appreciated.

Comment: Ah, I've solved my problem: the RAM wasn't seated properly. Maybe the memory is used by the onboard graphics, but it works properly now.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see on [this website](http://www.bioscentral.com/beepcodes/compaqbeep.htm), it does appear that you are correct about what the beep code means. In any computer, there is always a video card, there has to be, and like any other component, it can fail. In this case, it appears it did fail. It does appear to be integrated. It also appears it has an AGP slot, so you can buy an AGP video card to use in the system in place of the integrated card.

Comment: It doesn't have a video card. There is a point where a video chip can be soldered to it which connects to the internal AGP bus, but there is no slot with it.

Answer (score 0):

1-long 2-short is pretty widely known as a problem with video. This can mean that the monitor cable has come loose (not everything can run headless), or that the on-motherboard graphics chip has smoked itself. If it isn't simply the monitor cable, fixing this will require putting a separate graphics card in the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem! DeskPro EN. I added a different video card and it started right up, bypassing the on-board graphics. I figured out the problem with the old AGP card was that the capacitor had died on it too- once that was replaced, it was good as new.

As for the on-board graphics, Im confident that is a capacitor issue too. I replaced the caps on the motherboard, and now the on-board video is working too.

I suppose Compaq didn't really expect these things to still be in use in some places 20+ years later. Still, the machine ran fine with the old caps once it had a working video card, so if you can source another AGP video card, you can get it to run again without having to solder a thing.

Good luck!